# glibc not properly compiling

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86, glibc

While compiling `glibc 2.11`, I get the following error. Any idea how to solve this.

```
In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/syslog.c:10:
../misc/syslog.c: In function ‘__vsyslog_chk’:
../misc/syslog.c:123: sorry, unimplemented: inlining failed in call to ‘syslog’: function body not available
../misc/syslog.c:155: sorry, unimplemented: called from here
make[2]: *** [/home/alice/Desktop/glib-build/misc/syslog.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alice/Desktop/glibc-2.11/misc'
make[1]: *** [misc/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alice/Desktop/glibc-2.11'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Why do you compile glibc? It is a so central piece of software that compiling it requires a lot of expertise! Installing a newer distribution (perhaps in a chroot-ed environment) is probably simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [known problem with building `glibc` on Ubuntu](http://plash.beasts.org/wiki/GlibcBuildIssues#head-b9149fbab065967691cf1bade23d84325c05e9b0). In essence:

[`glibc` does not build with `_FORTIFY_SOURCE` enabled](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10375), and Ubuntu compiles stuff with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2`.

You need to disable this by undefining `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`. i.e. *append* `-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to your `CFLAGS`.